# Django like button dosen't increment and redirect me to the same page

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with like button it doesn't work at all. In the template I use 
`{{ post.likes }}` to show likes count  and for the button I use `<a href="{% url 'post_like' pk=post.pk %}" class="btn btn-block hvr-bounce-in">`

This is views.py

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect, render_to_response
from django.template import Context
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.generic import View

from blog.forms import CommentForm, PostForm, SearchForm
from blog.models import Post


def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')[0:50]
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html', {'posts': posts})


def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})


def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/add_comment_to_post.html', {'form': form})


def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/add_post.html', {'form': form})


def search_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        search_text = request.POST['search-form']
    else:
        search_text = ''
    posts = Post.objects.filter(title__contains=search_text)
    return render_to_response('blog/search.html', {'post': posts})


def post_like(request, pk):
    if pk:
        post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
        count = post.likes
        count += 1
        post.likes = count
        post.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('post/%s/like/' % pk)


def dislike_post(request, pk):
    if pk:
        post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
        post.dislikes += 1
        post.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('post/%s/like/' % pk)
```

and for urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/comment/$', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    url(r'^search/$', views.search_view, name='search'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/like/$', views.post_like, name='post_like'),
    # url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/dislike/$', views.dislike_post, name='post_dislike'),
]
```

Edit : For the model.py this is the code I use :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)
    image = VersatileImageField(upload_to='images')
    tags = TaggableManager()
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.ImageField(default=0)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Please show your `Post` model.

Comment: I edited the question , thank you for the help sir :)

Comment: Which url do you want the `post_like` and `dislike_post` views to redirect to?

Comment: I want them to redirect to the detail_post urls  `url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail')` it's where the button like and dislike exist for example : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/5/` I didn't add ajax yet to my page

Comment: yor post_like and post_dislike are redirecting to the same url, HttpResponseRedirect should have the url you want in this case /post/pk/

Comment: I change it with '/post/%s' but dosen't work still the likes counter isn't incremented @lorenag83

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the url that your view redirects to, you just need to change the value that you pass to `HttpResponseRedirect`.

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/post/%s/' % pk)
```

Note that the url starts with a slash. You can use `reverse`, to prevent hardcoding the url

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def post_like(request, pk):
    ...
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[pk]))
```

I'm not sure why the `likes` count is not increasing. In your view, I would add some print statements to try and work out what is going on, for example:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def post_like(request, pk):
    print("In post_like")
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    print("likes before: ", post.likes)
    post.likes += 1
    post.save()
    print("likes after: ", post.likes)
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=pk)
```

Note that I have used the `redirect` shortcut to simplify the code. You don't need the `if pk` statement, because `pk` is a required argument.

Comment: Thank you so much , I fixed the problem with the button now (I forgot to add {% url 'post_like' pk=post.pk %} to the like button now it works)